# About sculpting workflow

Tags: workflow, sculpting, retopology

I sculped my mesh which is very dense.Then I retopologized it and added a multiresolution modifer to add details(As youtubers suggest).But doing this increases the polycount and actually kills all the effort I made to make the mesh animation friendly and lowpoly.Do I have to retopologize my mesh again to make it lowpoly again?

Comment: Normally if you increase details with Multires modifier it means you still intend sculpting which is the contrary to optimization, you create another highpoly. And usually in case of Multires the base mesh is the lowpoly mesh for baking

Comment: yes, why did you give a multires to your retopologized version, the retopologized should be the last version, i.e. the most low-poly, multires is like a high-poly version, it's another way to create a high-poly version and to sculpt, it's a bit like dyntopo

Comment: I didn't do it yet! I just completed the retopology and found out I lost almost all the details from the original sculpt! Then went to youtube and found out that details should be added onthe multi resolution retopomesh got a bit confused there

Comment: If you mean workflow similar to [this one by Cgcookie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MU7EQjauKNo) then the mesh which got details from dyntopo by means of Multires is the highpoly and its copy without Multires is lowpoly.

Comment: Yes exactly that, but it will eventually increase the polycount (multires mod).Then what is the purpose of retopology in the first time?or is it an unique workflow where you need to retopologize the mesh twice?